# integrate Google Sky Map into an application

Tags: android, google-api

I want to integrate [Google Sky Map](http://www.google.com/mobile/skymap/) in my application.  Does it have an API?

What steps should be taken to integrate with this service, and how can I integrate it in an application?

Answer (score 4):

Was also looking for a way, but didn't find one.

One of the [developers](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b3440d10a74001b4/ef840c3cfea6a00c#ef840c3cfea6a00c) said this 6-7 months ago about integration/API

> I'm one  of the developers on the Sky Map project.  At present there
>   are no intents defined beyond the search intents.  If you just want to
>   point at a particular named target you could try those.  At the moment
>   we don't support kml or other Intents though.

If you do happen to find some new information, please share.

Answer (score 2):

To call Google Sky Map from within your application:

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
i.setPackage("com.google.android.stardroid");
i.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "mars");
startActivity(i);